# How to export demo.dump or demo.sql file to Heroku database

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a `dump/sql` file on local system which I want to export to Heroku database. I found a command from Heroku [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export) but it contains s3 URL and I don't have s3 account.
so how can I export local db backup file to Heroku?
Thanks

Comment: Please refer to [this link] (https://gist.github.com/kagemusha/1569836)

Answer (score 0):

heroku psql heroku_database_name < local_dump.sql

This worked for me

Comment: please give local file complete address as (/home/hamza/Downloads/ats_db_plain.sql)